# MPMoviePlayerController should play the video without audio in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

Using`[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:value];` will show volume popup, which I don't want. Can anyone tell me a way to mute the audio. `MPMoviePlayerController` should play the video without audio.

Thanks Inadvance.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in two different ways, you can try either of them:

**First option:**
Include `AVFoundation` framework and write this:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:&error];
```

**Second option:**

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:0];
```

Comment: I tried with the first option aswell, still audio is coming.